# How to populate jqgrid from a Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

Hi im working on MVC project which uses **jqgrid**. I have an **master** grid . On click of the row and **edit** button im goin to CreateOrEdit view . In that view there is a one more grid -*Detail* grid.

In case of *create*: the fields for the master grid(*labels* and respective *EditorFor*) and the detail grid will be empty and once we populate everything(labels and respective *EditorFor* and the grid) and click on save .. it gets saved.. This much work is done. Now the problem..

While *editing*: I have to populate the detail grid depending on the Id selected in the master grid.

I've tried things like:

```
url:'@Url.Action("PDVs", "GetData", new { pdv = @Model.Details})'
data: JSON.stringify('@(Model.Details)')
```

and/or specifying the url as:

```
url:'/PDVs/GetData'
```

And in the `Controller`:

```
public JsonResult GetData(Details details)
```

So as to receive the model and query it and send the `JsonResult` back, 
but the model `details` is getting `null` values for all the fields.

So can someone please give me any ideas of how to solve this problem?

**Update**: The Details Model is

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Repository.Pattern.Ef6;

namespace Abc.PROJECTS.Models
{
    public partial class PDVDuration:Entity
    {
        public int PDVDurationId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> PDVId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateFrom { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateTo { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string Remarks { get; set; }
       public virtual PDV PDV { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And this is my details grid:

```
jQuery("#DetailsGrid").jqGrid({

           //  url: '/PDVs/GetManintenance',

            // datatype: 'json',

         @*url:'@Url.Action("PDVs", "GetData", new { pdv = @Model.PDVDurations })',*@
            mtype: 'GET',            

            //datatype: "local",
            //data: mydata,
            //data: JSON.pdv.PDVDuration,
           // data:myGridComplete('@Model.PDVDurations'),
            height: 100,
            width: 900,
            colNames: ['DateFrom', 'DateTo', 'Type', 'Remarks'],
            colModel: [
                {
                    name: 'DateFrom', index: 'DateFrom', width: 60, editable: true, sorttype: "date",
                    formatter: 'date',
                    formatoptions: {
                        srcformat: 'm/d/Y',
                        // newformat: 'd/m/Y '
                        //newformat: 'Y-m-d'
                },
                    editoptions: { dataInit: initDateEdit, size: 14 },

                },
                {
                    name: 'DateTo', index: 'DateTo', width: 80, editable: true, sorttype: "date",
                    formatter: 'date',
                    formatoptions: {
                        srcformat: 'm/d/Y',
                        //newformat: 'd/m/Y'
                    },
                    editoptions: { dataInit: initDateEdit, size: 14 },

                },


                {
                    name: 'Type', width: 80, editable: true, formatter: "select",
                    edittype: "select", editoptions: { value: "Open:Open;Maintainance:Maintainance;Closed:Closed", defaultValue: "Open" },


                },
                 {
                     name: 'Remarks', index: 'Remarks', width: 80, editable: true
                 }
                ,
            ],
            @*  data: JSON.stringify('@(Model.PDVDurations)'),*@
           // data:JSON.stringify(viewModel),
            //data:model,
            //model:viewModel,
            //data: JSON.parse(jsonData),
            pager: "#PDVMPager",
            loadonce: true,
            sortname: 'Client',
            ignoreCase: true,
            sortorder: 'asc',
            gridview: true,
            autoencode: true,
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50],
            caption: "Maintenance",
            viewrecords: true,

            editurl: "clientArray",
            gridComplete:function myGridComplete(PDV)
                {
                return JSON.stringify('@(Model.PDVDurations)')
                },


        }).jqGrid("navGrid", "#PDVMPager", {}, editSettings, addSettings, {
            multipleSearch: true,
            overlay: false,
            onClose: function () {

                $("div#ui-datepicker-div.ui-datepicker").hide();
            }
        }).jqGrid("filterToolbar", { defaultSearch: "cn" });
    });
```

Comment: can you show `Details` model? Also what `mtype` do you use in `jqgrid`?

Comment: your data is complex? Don't you want to sent to controller just id and get JsonResult as in your method?

Comment: Yes thats what i did later and got stuck again... while creating.. the model will be null .. so i get 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' Error. .Any ideas of how to check the model if its null and send the id as 0 or something? i tryd..` url: '@Url.Action("GetDurations", "PDVs", new {id=@Model.PDVId })',` and  function `checkIfNull()
        {

            if('@Model.IsEmpty')
            {
                var x=0;
            }
            else
            {
                var x = '@Model.PDVId';
            }
        }*@
       '

Comment: Is it possible to use the same jqgrid for both Create and edit purpose?! by using partial views..

Comment: How can i send the  url: '@Url.Action("GetDurations", "PDVs", new {id=@Model.PDVId })', only during Editing time and not during creating time.. ?

Comment: where do you get null refference exeption? On your View or in Controller?

Comment: In my view . Because of the URL: paramater of grid which is present i view.. as i WAS using the same grid for Creating and editing... while creating.. this piece of code - new {id=@Model.PDVId })' is throwing an error cos i guess Model will be null while creating...?(duh)

Comment: So, you should check the model on null then. `new {id=@(Model.PDVId.HasValue ? Model.PDVId.Value : 0 })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have problem with `Url.Action` method if you want url like you wrote you should flip params.

Anyway, i suppose you can try to write like this in your jqgrid init if you need **whole model**:

```
url: '@Url.Action("GetData", "PDVs")',
postData: '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))'
```

But if you need just **some fields** you can write like this:

```
url: '@Url.Action("GetData", "PDVs")',
postData: 
{
   PDVDurations: @Model.PDVDurations
}
```

But you should write different signature in controller method. Like this:

```
public JsonResult GetData(int PDVDurations)
```